# Can anyone help me to understand how this upper and lower bound for the binomial coefficient are derived?

Tags: inequality, proof-explanation, exponential-function, binomial-coefficients

I found this very interesting [upper and lower bound](https://mathoverflow.net/a/236511/15915) for the binomial coefficient that is taken from a book that I have not heard of.

Could someone help me understand how it is derived?

Here is the inequality:

Let:

- $k>1,n>k$ be integers
- $h(x) = -x\ln(x) - (1-x)\ln(1-x)$

Then:

$$\left(\sqrt{\frac{n}{8k(n-k)}}\right)e^{nh(k/n)} \le {n \choose k} \le \left(\sqrt{\frac{n}{2\pi{k}(n-k)}}\right)e^{nh(k/n)}$$

I understand that it comes from [Stirling's Approximation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation) and the [binary entropy function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_entropy_function) with the details found in this [book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0471290483).

If anyone can offer tips on why this inequality holds, that will be very helpful.

Comment: Have a look at this good paper https://www.emis.de/journals/JIPAM/images/043_00_JIPAM/043_00_www.pdf

Comment: Thanks for posting!  Looks very interesting!